# Which server do I need to use for iOS latest news app?

Tags: ios, server

my supervisor told me to develop an iOS application. As you can see in the diagram, this application works as, for notification, there is the Push notification service, for the Application server, there is the web service and for the SMS notification, there is the SMS APIs. But in order to get the latest news inside the application, which server do I need to use?
(How the app works; if the user open the app, then in the 'News' tab, the user can check the latest news) I tried googling it, but I cannot find anything related with the News Server for iOS application. 
Thanks for your help..

[image: draft image of how app works]

Comment: Probably a web server with a RESTful API?

Comment: @Paulw11 is it like a third party to use in the iOS application? or just a web server ?

Comment: Just a web server. You will need to write code to run the on the web server to allow your app to retrieve the news or whatever from the database

Comment: @Paulw11 Write the codes inside my existing iOS application right? I tried googling but still confusing..

Comment: Both. You need code on iOS to talk to the web server and code in the web server to serve the data

Comment: @Paulw11 How to write the codes in the web server? Sorry, I am an intern at the company and I have never worked with the web servers before.. Can you share me the useful websites I can take reference to? Thank you so much...

Comment: this is pretty hard to answer because there are thousands of server and architecture in different languages

Comment: @benso at least now I know that we need to use restful api in order to do the news function in our iOS app.. okay thanks